# Using smartwatch Android as Beacon scanner

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os, ibeacon, estimote

I'm currently trying to use a smartwatch LG G Watch R (fully updated) as a Beacon Scanner.
The Beacons are made by Estimote, so I'm using its [SDK](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK).
Using the smartphone I have no problem at all, but with the smartwatch I receive the signal from the beacons every 5 seconds despite having set both on the app and on the beacons the advertising time at 325ms.

The code is basically the same used on the smartphone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the LG watch, but I realized similar behavior with other devices, like the Moto G2 for example. Even though the code is exactly the same, different devices handle it differently. It might be due to different chipsets used or how they are implemented.

Go to the logcat (without filtering the app) and look at the times when scans are started, stopped and when results are received. You might see that the scan process makes random "breaks" for no visible reason. Maybe it's the same issue with your watch.
Unfortunately I don't know about a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try that.
Anyway I think it could also be a problem of the Estimote SDK since it hasn't been tested on Android Wear.

Comment: Any news on this? Was anyone able to use a watch to detect iBeacon somehow ?